# Is gamma correction algorithm same for RGB as for grayscale?

Tags: image-processing, rgb, grayscale

Is gamma correction algorithm same for RGB as for grayscale images?

I know how to do gamma correction for one-channel grayscale image. Do I do the same thing
for all channels in RGB image? Or is there a different algorithm?

THanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use different values for gamma on each of the channels, but yes it is the same algorithm.

Comment: And perhaps "should" apply different gamma to each channel.  Very dependant on the type of imager, and display being used!!!  Good answer, this is what I would have said :-) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the RGB image to HSL color space and apply the gamma only on the Luma channel.

Comment: This isnt really a great answer. This is only going to essentially change the overall brightness, and by itself this is NOT gamma correction. Most imagers and monitors function on the RGB colorspace and because of this the gamma correction should be applied here (in RGB) to correct for the non-linearities of each channel separately.